# Updated spyder but packages are disappearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I updated my spyder from 3.3.6 to 4.0.1 and since then my libraries are not getting compiled , like pandas library, sklearn , and few other .

I don't know why it's happening . Normal import statements show error . Even numpy did the same , so i just ran `pip install numpy` in the ipython console and then it got solved .

**Is there no other alternative? Spyder 3.6 worked just fine without running the pip command in the ipython console .**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
```

for now i used ipython commands to install the entire library again (`pip install sklearn`).

Can someone help me out with a permanent fix?

Comment: And how did you update spyder?

Comment: @roganjosh through anaconda, on the right top corner of spyder tile there is settings , from there .